# System GMM Estimator

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, moments

Consider the dynamic linear model given by:
\begin{equation}
y_{it} = \rho y_{i,t-1} + \alpha_i + \nu_{it}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_i$ represents individual fixed effects. The GMM two-step estimator imposes $0.5(T-1)(T-2)$ moment restrictions, specifically:
\begin{equation}
E[y_{i,t-s} \Delta \nu_{it}] = 0
\end{equation}
for $t=3,\ldots,T$ and $s \ge 2$.

The System-GMM estimator (Bundell and Bond, 1998) extends these moment restrictions beyond the first differenced equations to also include the levels equation. This is achieved by assuming a mild stationarity assumption (mean stationarity) on the series $y_{it}$. Can you provide insight into how imposing a mild stationarity assumption on the series ensures the validity of the following moment restrictions:
\begin{equation}
E[\Delta y_{i,t-1} (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})] = 0
\end{equation}
for $t=3,\ldots,T$

If I understand correctly, mean stationarity is imposed by assuming the following initial moment condition:
\begin{equation}
E[\Delta y_{i2} \alpha_i]=0
\end{equation}
Due to mean stationarity, the steady-state value of $y_{it}$ is $E[y_{it}|\alpha_i] = \frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho}$. The data-generating process (DGP) for $y_{i1}$ can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
y_{i1} = \frac{\alpha_i}{1-\rho} + e_{i1}
\end{equation}
where $e_{i1}$ is the disturbance term.

Then, for the first period observed (at $t=2$), $y_{i2}=\rho y_{i1}+ \alpha_i+ \nu_{it}$, and by subtracting $y_{i1}$ from the left and the right and using the above definition for $y_{i1}$, I write:
\begin{equation}
\Delta y_{i2} = (\rho −1)  e_{i1}+ \nu_{i2}
\end{equation}
Using this expression into the initial moment condition, It can be expressed as
\begin{equation}
E[\Delta y_{i2} \alpha_i]=E\left([(\rho−1) e_{i1}+\nu_{i2}] \alpha_i]\right)=0
\end{equation}
which holds under the assumption that $E[e_{i1} \alpha_i]=0$

How this allows me to write
\begin{equation}
E[\Delta y_{i,t-1} (\alpha_i + \nu_{it})] = 0
\end{equation}
for $t=3,\ldots,T$